# Problema ao realizar o cálculo entre arrays

Tags: python-3.x

Estou construindo um código que tem uma estrutura muito parecida com o código abaixo.

```
from math import sin, pi
from numpy import zeros
djn = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
djn = array(djn)

def test(djn):
   M = len(djn)
   delta = zeros(M, float)
   delta[0:M] = 0.409279709 * sin(((2*pi)/365)*(284+djn[0:M]))
   return delta

res = test(djn)
```

A ideia é que o argumento da função seja um array, bem como a saída da mesmo. Entretanto eu tenho obtido o seguinte erro:

```
only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Porém eu já vi estruturs parecidas com essa e não estou conseguindo ver meu erro.

Agradeço a colaboração :)

Comment: O único problema com o código acima é que você não está carregando `array`, `sin` e  `pi`. Veja [aqui](https://ideone.com/xnWoel). Entretanto se o código é diferente e o erro que vc colocou é o que acontece no outro código, use o `np.vectorize`

Comment: Eu acabei não colocando, mas estava usando o ```sin``` e o ``pi`` do ```math``` e não do ```numpy```

Comment: use o `sin` do `numpy`. Só isso é o suficiente pra resolver o problema

Comment: @Syner eu sei que não está relacionado com o problema, mas eu percebi também que você escreveu um termo `2*pi/365` dentro do seno e estava imaginando se não seria `360` porque parece que você queria converter graus pra radiano, certo?

Answer (score 0):

Você está recebendo o erro "only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" porque a função espera um único valor em vez disso, você passou uma matriz.

use a biblioteca do [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sin.html) no lugar do math.

```
import numpy as np

djn = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
djn = np.array(djn)

def test(djn):
   M = len(djn)
   delta = np.zeros(M, float)
   delta[0:M] = 0.409279709 * np.sin(((2*np.pi)/365)*(284+djn[0:M]))
   return delta

res = test(djn)
print(res)
```

Comment: Desculpe mas tem um erro no seu código. O djn tem que estar dentro do seno. Você fez `sin(2pi/365)*djn`, mas era pra ser `sin(2pi*djn/365)`

Comment: @FlavioMoraes, verdade acabei removendo os parentes.